# How to know object from which method is called?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a static class, which methods is called from instances of another class. How I can to know which instance has called method **without some adding method parameters**?

Example:

```
static class SomeStaticClass
{
 public static void SomeGreatMethod (/*NO PARAMETERS*/)
 {
   LittleClass caller = //How to obtain caller instance here?
 }
}

class LittleClass
{
 public void SomeMethod ()
 {
   //some code
   SomeStaticClass.SomeGreatMethod (/*NO PARAMETERS*/);
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you don't want to add the caller as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a [StackFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx) and read from it entire stack trace

Answer (score 2):

You can potentially find out which *class* contains the calling method by creating a stack trace - although inlining can mess this up.

You can't find out which *instance* is making the call unless you're using the debugging API.

If you need to do *either* of these things, you've probably got a design problem. There are some areas of the framework which do something similar to impose security, but that's a pretty rare case. Normally, if you need that information in `SomeGreatMethod`, you should simply provide it as part of the call - or make it an *instance* method in a non-static class, and provide the appropriate contextual information on construction.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, you need to use the callstack

http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-calling-method-name/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use this

```
private static Type GetCallingMethodHolderType()
{
   const int iCallDeepness = 0; //can vary this ...
   System.Diagnostics.StackTrace stack = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(false);
   System.Diagnostics.StackFrame sframe = stack.GetFrame(iCallDeepness);
   return sframe.GetMethod().ReflectedType; //This will return a TYPE which holds the method.
}
```

**EDIT**

I edited the post in order to return the TYPE of the object wich holds the caller method. 
*Instance*, like you requested, imo, it's not possible to get.

*Should* work for you.

Comment: They're not asking for the calling method name though, they're after the calling instance.